# Solve the knapsack problem

Tags: code-golf

### Knapsack Problem

(Actually, this is a **subset of real [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)**.... - there's nothing to optimize!)

The knapsack problem is:

> Given positive integers [image: a_1, a_2, ...], and an integer S, find non-negative integers [image: u_1, u_2, ...] satisfies [image: \sum_{i} a_i u_i = S]

... or in (my bad) English...

> Suppose you have many stuffs which weights [image: a_1, a_2, ...], find configurations of those stuffs which weights S.

### Problem

> Find **all** configurations of stuffs, which information is given by input.

### Input

You can make your own format, but you should enable users to input **the sum of stuffs(S)**, **weights of stuffs [image: a_1, a_2, ...], and names of each stuffs**.

Stuffs' name may contain `[a-zA-Z0-9 _]` (alphanumeric + `_` + space).

You may assume that the input is correct, [image: a_1, a_2, ...] are positive, and S is non-negative.

For example, consider this pseudo-real world situation, where a man orders appetizers worth exactly $15.05:

[image: First cell of xkcd.com/287]

A possible input is:

```
1505
215 Mixed fruit
275 French fries
335 Side salad
355 Hot wings
420 Mozzarella sticks
580 Sampler plate
```

### Output

Print all possible configurations (no same configurations, one configuration per one line, each line contains pairs of amount of a stuff and name of the stuff).

Stuff with zero amount can be omitted.

If there's no configuration possible, simply print `X`.

### Example

Input and output format (and order) can be vary.

This is JS code I made roughly:

```
var s=prompt(),a=s.split('/'),b=[],c,i=1,t=a[0];while(i<a.length){c=a[i].split(/^([^ ]*) /);c.shift();b.push(c);i++;}
var d=[],l=b.length,p=0,_=0;for(i=0;i<l;i++)d[i]=0;
function as(x,y){for(var i=0,s=0;i<x.length;i++)s+=x[i][0]*y[i];return s}
function cs(x,y){for(var i=0,s='';i<x.length;i++)s+=y[i]+' '+x[i][1]+', ';return s}
while(p>=0){
    p=0;
    while((q=as(b,d))>=t){
        if(q==t){console.log(cs(b,d));_=1}
        d[p]=0;p++;if(p>=l){p=-1;break;}
        d[p]++;
    }
    if(p==0) d[0]++;
}
if(!_) console.log('X');
```

---

Input

`1505/215 Mixed fruit/275 French fries/335 Side salad/355 Hot wings/420 Mozzarella sticks/580 Sampler plate`

Output

```
7 Mixed fruit, 0 French fries, 0 Side salad, 0 Hot wings, 0 Mozzarella sticks, 0 Sampler plate, 
1 Mixed fruit, 0 French fries, 0 Side salad, 2 Hot wings, 0 Mozzarella sticks, 1 Sampler plate,
```

---

Input

`5/1 A/1 B/1 C`

Output

```
5 A, 0 B, 0 C, 
4 A, 1 B, 0 C, 
3 A, 2 B, 0 C, 
2 A, 3 B, 0 C, 
1 A, 4 B, 0 C, 
0 A, 5 B, 0 C, 
4 A, 0 B, 1 C, 
3 A, 1 B, 1 C, 
2 A, 2 B, 1 C, 
1 A, 3 B, 1 C, 
0 A, 4 B, 1 C, 
3 A, 0 B, 2 C, 
2 A, 1 B, 2 C, 
1 A, 2 B, 2 C, 
0 A, 3 B, 2 C, 
2 A, 0 B, 3 C, 
1 A, 1 B, 3 C, 
0 A, 2 B, 3 C, 
1 A, 0 B, 4 C, 
0 A, 1 B, 4 C, 
0 A, 0 B, 5 C,
```

---

Input

`10/20 A/11 B`

Output

`X`

---

Input

`250/35 Portal 2/21 Minecraft/12 Braid`

Output

```
5 Portal 2, 3 Minecraft, 1 Braid, 
2 Portal 2, 8 Minecraft, 1 Braid, 
2 Portal 2, 4 Minecraft, 8 Braid, 
2 Portal 2, 0 Minecraft, 15 Braid,
```

Input

`250/33 Portal 2/21 Minecraft/12 Braid`

Output

`X`

---

### Winner

Since this is the code golf game, person with shortest code win.

If two codes have same length, then a code with highest votes win.

Comment: How does it make sense to count `\n` but not `\r`?  That's just favoring certain platforms, and/or tools that don't care which you use.

Comment: @Matthew It's for Windows - since it uses \r\n while Linux uses \n, the amount of code in Windows is increased by number of lines.

Comment: Wait, does Mac use \r?

Comment: OK, -1 then.  There are so many things wrong with that (besides the bias that is in no way related to the problem).  To start: I use Linux line endings in my files on Windows, and the code samples here don't tell you what's what.

Comment: @MatthewRead I removed that. If you can't understand example inputs and outputs (BTW, the dirty javascript code is for testing purpose..), then I'll tell you that first input example is same to the input under `A possible input is:`.

Comment: This has been beaten to death already, the consensus is that line endings are equal on whatever platform, no need to discuss/even mention it over and over again.  http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167/line-break-formats-and-character-numbers

Comment: [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/287/) is on SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python, 185 chars

```
S,C,N=input()
R=range(len(C))
F=lambda i,w:sum([[x+[j]for x in F(j,w-C[j])]for j in R[i:]],[])if w>0 else[[]][w<0:]
for L in F(0,S):print[(L.count(i),N[i])for i in R];S=0
if S:print'X'
```

run it with input like this:

```
echo "[1505,[215,275,335,355,420,580],['MF','FF','SS','HW','MS','SP']]" | ./knapsack.py
```

which encodes S, a list of costs, and a list of item names corresponding to those costs.

It outputs list of item counts and item names:

```
[(7, 'MF'), (0, 'FF'), (0, 'SS'), (0, 'HW'), (0, 'MS'), (0, 'SP')]
[(1, 'MF'), (0, 'FF'), (0, 'SS'), (2, 'HW'), (0, 'MS'), (1, 'SP')]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 59 chars

```
Tally/@IntegerPartitions[#1,All,#2/._[x_,_]->x]/.#2/.{}->X&
```

Invoke with

```
%[1505, {215 -> "MF", 275 -> "FF", 335 -> "SS", 355 -> "HW", 420 -> "MS", 580 -> "SP"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Ruby, 136 characters

```
a,*b=*$<
c=->s,u,e{f,*r=e;f ?(0..s/h=f.to_i).map{|n|c[s-n*h,u+[n.to_s+f[/ .*/]],r]}:s>0?[]:u*?,}
r=c[a.to_i,[],b].flatten
puts r[0]?r:?X
```

Input must be given on STDIN, one line for the total amount and then one line per item (weight, followed by space, followed by name).

Example input:

```
250
35 Portal 2
21 Minecraft
12 Braid
```

Output:

```
2 Portal 2,0 Minecraft,15 Braid
2 Portal 2,4 Minecraft,8 Braid
2 Portal 2,8 Minecraft,1 Braid
5 Portal 2,3 Minecraft,1 Braid
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Python, 356 characters

I took a slight hit for reading from the command line:

```
from sys import argv
x=int(argv[1])
t=argv[3::2]
c=argv[2::2]
n=len(t)
s=[0]*n
d=1
g=1
while d:
    i=0
    s[i]+=1
    while int(c[i])*s[i]>x:
        s[i]=0
        if i+1>=n:
            d=0
        else:
            i+=1
            s[i]+=1
    if d and sum(map(lambda y:int(c[y])*s[y],range(n)))==x:
        g=0
        print zip(t, s)
if g:print"X"
```

Example input:

```
python stuff.py 1505 215 'Mixed fruit' 275 'French fries' 335 'Side salad' 355 'Hot wings' 420 'Mozzarella sticks' 580 'Sampler plate'
```

Output:

```
[('Mixed fruit', 7), ('French fries', 0), ('Side salad', 0), ('Hot wings', 0), ('Mozzarella sticks', 0), ('Sampler plate', 0)]
[('Mixed fruit', 1), ('French fries', 0), ('Side salad', 0), ('Hot wings', 2), ('Mozzarella sticks', 0), ('Sampler plate', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (V8), 225 bytes

```js
(t,k,l,a=d=0)=>[...Array(t+1)].flatMap((_,j)=>[...Array(k[L="length"]**j)].map((_,i)=>eval("r=[];while(j-r[L])r.push(i%k[L]),i=i/k[L]|0;r")).filter(p=>(a=m=d=0,p.map(i=>(a+=k[i],d|=i<m,m=i)),a==t&&!d)).map(p=>p.map(i=>l[i])))
```

I had a bunch of really neat ideas for how to golf this but they ended up not working.