# Batt to the Basics

Tags: code-golf, number

One of your acquaintances has a hobby of making make-shift electrical gadgets using various types of batteries. However, since they're thrifty, they want to use as few batteries as possible for their projects. This challenge uses several types of batteries; your job is to output the fewest number of batteries that will output a given voltage when chained together.

#### The batteries you'll be using

Here are the types of batteries you will be using, along with their ID numbers (I assigned those for this challenge) and their output voltages:

1. AA 1.5V
2. Button battery 3V
3. Li-ion battery 3.7V
4. 9V battery 9V
5. Car battery 12V

Batteries can also be half-charged, meaning that their voltage is half of what it is fully charged (I've removed any batteries who's half-voltages are the voltages of any full batteries):

6. ½ AA .75V
7. ½ Li-ion 1.85V
8. ½ 9V battery 4.5V
9. ½ Car battery 6V

#### The rules

- Input `i` must be a float where `1 ≤ i ≤ 100`, and where `i` has 1 or 2 decimal digits.
- Output must be a list of the *fewest number* of battery ID numbers (as listed above) that, when combined, will output the voltage, **or** an empty list (or any other empty value) if the voltage can't be produced using the above batteries. Alternatively, the list can consist of the *voltages* of the batteries used; however, the voltages **must** correspond with one of the batteries above.

Here are some test cases (the numbers aren't very large right now because of the time it takes to run the code for large numbers):

```
input: 1.5
output: [1.5]

input: 2
output: [] or None

input: 7.5
output: [6, 1.5]

input: 15
output: [12, 3]
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the fewest bytes wins!

Comment: 3.7 `!=` 2*1.875: did you mean 3.75 instead?

Comment: @SegFaultPlus4 No, I meant 1.85, but thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Why all required voltages are k/4?

Comment: @l4m2 Well, it makes less likely that a voltage will be input that can't be made with these batteries. I can remove that requirement if you like.

Comment: This makes the 1/2 Li-ion only as 9.25

Comment: @l4m2 [Edited.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/245671/revisions)

Comment: Can you please clarify in the spec what it means for batteries to 'make up' a voltage?

Comment: @chunes [Edited.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/245671/revisions)

Comment: @SylvesterKruin It is still not clear to me, as I am not well-versed in physics. Is the final voltage simply the sum of the voltages of the batteries that are chained together?

Comment: @chunes Yes, that was what I was trying to convey. If you like, you can edit the question with the wording of your choice. I'm thinking I should have waited longer in the Sandbox. Everyone seems to love to give feedback _after_ the challenge is already on the main site...

Comment: This might be considered a duplicate of [Solve the knapsack problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3731/53748). (Of course, it isn't strictly a "duplicate" but rather it's the same but with a pre-defined list of items and their values)

Comment: @JonathanAllan In that case, do you have any advice on how long to keep questions in the Sandbox? It seems that it needs to be longer than a couple days. Nobody said a thing about the answer there, and yet when I post the question, within the first hour people have 5 things to complain about, that nobody even mentioned in the Sandbox! If you think I should, I'll delete this question.

Comment: Sorry that you did not get the feedback in the sandbox (I'm not sure it works all that well really, I for one visit it rarely). Oftentimes one will get a bunch of feedback as soon as one posts to main, but usually that just means being around for the first couple of hours ready to address concerns and queries.

Comment: Can we output some other nullish value for voltages that can't be produced? Also, must the list of batteries be as short as a possible? It might be worth adding that to the rules, not just brief

Comment: @Matthew [Yes.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/245671/revisions).

Comment: Please consider provide some testcases so everyone may test their answers.

Comment: May I input value in (1/100V) so input be an integer to avoid float point errors?

Comment: @tsh [Yes. Done.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/245671/revisions)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 98 bytes

```javascript
f=(v,s=[],...y)=>s[v*7|0]?'':eval(s)+v?f(v,...y,...[1.5,3,3.7,9,12,.75,1.85,4.5,6].map(e=>s+-e)):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxBDoIwEIXhvRehI8OECgXFVA5CWDTYGg1SYk0TE@9e2626mcWX/81NeeWmx3V9Fos96xCMZB6dHEYkohfIkxv8tn2XY59lnfZqZg5y35tYpSCdgZPACitq8YB8h9QK5LQXWEdvRrqrlen4KC80QOfCcTPZxdlZ02wvzLA4B/jG@h@W1PwiT2H4AA)

Return voltages splitted by `-`

```javascript
f=(v,s=[],...y)=> // s,...y as testing buffer
    s[v*7|0]?'':  // The longest outputLength/input case, -0.75, need *6.67
    eval(s)+v?    // not equal?
        f(        // continue
            v,
            ...y,
            ...[1.5,3,3.7,9,12,.75,1.85,4.5,6].map(e=>s+-e))
    :s
```

Comment: The spec (currently) says we must output an empty list if not possible - this keeps recursing - 3.25 for example.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Yes this requires lots of memory and time to return an empty list because I stop loop only using `s[v*99|0]`

Comment: @JonathanAllan Get enough RAM and enough patience, 3.25 would take 10^70 time and memory

Comment: If 99 stops us, why does `18.5` (3.7 * 5) give a recursion error? Is 99 not enough or is there a language setting that needs tweaking?

Comment: @JonathanAllan  this usually require lots of stack

Comment: @JonathanAllan Added not possible test case

Comment: Ah, I see - yeah if we just do `f(v...y,,s+-1.5,s+-3.7)` it'd work on TIO.

Comment: Probably worth explicitly stating the quirks in your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>170</s> 169 bytes

```
from itertools import*
f=lambda i:next(filter(None,(next((x for x in product([1.5,3,3.75,9,12,.75,1.85,4.5,6],repeat=n)if sum(x)==i),0)for n in range(int(i/.75)+2))),())
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY47DoJAEIZ7T7HljI4oKIomXMELGAuUXZ0EdskyJHgWGxpNPJK3EXx0f_5XvtujusrF2a67N2KmyetpvCsVi_biXFErLivnZTwyaZGVxzxTvLW6FTBc9B3YOasJPg60yjivWsVWVd7lzUlgHwYxLWgRrGPaUBjRIMIgiWnZB6sDeV3pTFKLbFTdlNBimjLSHIcrO1z5zJ41sBXgWb_GSYSIBIhf4B_3n_8N)

10 bytes could be saved by replacing `range(int(i/.75)+2)` with `range(41)`, but then it may not find the correct solution if `i>30`. I prefer the longer version, since it is correct for any (numeric) input.

Note: it is *extremely* inefficient, but it eventually terminates for every input.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
•UyмµñFb₃^•₅в20/₃иæé.ΔOQ
```

Outputs a list of the voltages of the batteries, and `-1` if it can't find a result.

[(Don't) try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOi0MoLew5tPbzRLelRU3McUOBRU@uFTUYG@kDuhR2Hlx1eqXduin/g///GAA) (Will time out for all test cases.)

If we remove the `é` it can be somewhat tested, but it won't output the required shortest result anymore: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOi0MoLew5tPbzRLelRU3McUOBRU@uFTUYG@kDuhR2Hl@mdm@If@P@/oQEA). (And might still time-out.)
And with only `•UyмµñFb₃^•₅в20/₃иæ` we can see all the possible powerset lists: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOi0MoLew5tPbzRLelRU3McUOBRU@uFTUYG@kDuhR2Hl/3/DwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
•UyмµñFb₃^•     # Push compressed integer 540570253786318174620
 ₅в             # Convert it to base-255 as list: [30,60,74,180,240,15,37,90,120]
   20/          # Divide each by 20: [1.5,3,3.7,9,12,0.75,1.85,4.5,6]
      ₃и        # Cycle-repeat this list 95 times
                # (95 is the lowest 1-byte constant above 40, which is required to
                # reach the maximum to support input 30 with the lowest voltage 0.75)
        æ       # Pop and push its powerset
         é      # Sort it by length
          .Δ    # Find the first inner list which is truthy for:
                # (or -1 if none were truthy)
            O   #  Sum the list
             Q  #  Check if it's equal to the (implicit) input-float
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96361/tips-for-golfing-in-05ab1e) to understand why `•UyмµñFb₃^•` is `540570253786318174620` and `•UyмµñFb₃^•₅в` is `[30,60,74,180,240,15,37,90,120]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 126 bytes

Recursive brute-force solution.
Throws exception if no solution is found.

```python
lambda n:(g:=lambda i,s=0,l=[]:[l]*(s==i)if s>=i else[b[0]for a in[12,9,6,4.5,3.7,3,1.85,1.5,.75]if(b:=g(i,s+a,l+[a]))])(n)[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PczBagMhFAXQdfIVbzfavAyZTm0SwfyIdeG0On1gdVALDSHfPjVQurlwuZezXOtniuNpyatXb2uwX9OHhSjZLNVfISzqgEFpI3UwT6woRZw8lIsicKE4PemD8SlD@0Y9POMZX/GlFzj2Rxxx6E@ihcD@KAx5Nkk1s4buLIadtoZzw1nkzVgfCDUEso2zYwMOgsvtpuarXDLFynx3ozvsL3DzjPi949uN@3l3S/3fY4KSwnelFOHBtX/H118)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), 95 bytes

Returns a singleton list containing the solution. Based on [friddo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245689/64121).

```python
f=lambda i,*l:sum([f(i,*l,ord(b)/20)for b in'ð´xZJ<%'],[])[:1]if i>sum(l)else[l][sum(l)>i:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc0xDoIwFMbx3cUbmLc07TMlCsalUQ7gEWw6QKD6klKagoncysET6MEqxO37hl/@YRrvvT9kYQpTSvbsqq5uKiC5dWp4dEJbsWzZx0bUuCv2aPsINZDn39fn/bxeTmyz5kZqg1rlhixQuUCHrRta7Yz@v5KUSYul2UKs/K0VucyPqFYAIZIfBWdFA1kJbODAYO7CHEfE9AM)

Comment: Woah, can you please explain that cryptic string?

Comment: @friddo If you multiply the voltage values by 20 you get integers. Each character in the string represents such a voltage*20 by its unicode codepoint.

Comment: ah!, that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 29 bytes

```
» 3J↔kṫ₅uR»₈τ20/41ẋfṗÞṡ'∑⁰=;h
```

[Don't try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJUIiwiIiwiwrsgM0rihpRr4bmr4oKFdVLCu+KCiM+EMjAvNDHhuotm4bmXw57huaEn4oiR4oGwPTtoIiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==) (it times out)

Add `vøḋ` to the end if it can't be returned as list of rationals instead of decimals. `vøḋ` will return a list of strings, tho. Returns `0` if it can't find a solution.

You can somewhat test it without the `Þṡ`, but it won't return the optimal answer: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJUIiwiIiwiwrsgM0rihpRr4bmr4oKFdVLCu+KCiM+EMjAvNDHhuotm4bmXJ+KIkeKBsD07aCIsIiIsIjEwIl0=)

**Extremely** slow.

Port of 05AB1E.

### How?

```
» 3J↔kṫ₅uR»                   # Push compressed integer 557746805944978070136
           ₈τ                 # Convert to base 256: [30, 60, 74, 180, 240, 15, 37, 90, 120]
             20/              # Divide each by 20: [1.5, 3.0, 3.7, 9.0, 12.0, 0.75, 1.85, 4.5, 6.0]
                41ẋ           # Repeat that list 41 times: [[1.5, 3.0, ...], [1.5, 3.0, ...], ...]
                   f          # Flatten it: [1.5, 3.0, ..., 1.5, 3.0, ..., ...]
                    ṗ         # Powerset
                     Þṡ       # Sort by length (this is what slows it down so much)
                       '   ;  # Filter for:
                        ∑⁰=   # The sum of this list is equal to the input
                            h # Get the first item
```